# Pass a variable in a selector jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass a variable in a selector jquery but I don't find the right syntaxe.

I have this :

```
var jsonobject = eval(responseObject);

    for(var item in jsonobject)
    {
        $('#",jsonobject[item],"').css("background-color","red");                   
    }
```

So the variable is `jsonobject[item]` and I want to use the value in it as the name of the selector.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Side note: use `JSON.parse()`,  not `eval()` to parse the JSON response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
$("#"+jsonobject[item]).css("background-color","red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use string concatenation for that:

```
$('#' + jsonobject[item]).css(...);
```